# Contour integral with branch cut and cubic root

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am having fun with contour integration and I try to compute the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{z^{1/3}}{z^2+\pi^2}dz$$
This integral is equal to $\pi^{1/3}/\sqrt{3}$. However I cannot obtain that number! I work on a keyhole contour.

[image]

So this gives me
$$\oint_C f(z)dz=\int_r^Rf(z)dz+\int_\Gamma f(z)dz+\int_R^rf(z)dz+\int_\gamma f(z)dz.$$ Using ML-ineq. we see that the second and fourth integral vanishes so I'm leftover with
$$\oint_C f(z)dz=\int_r^Rf(z)dz+\int_R^rf(z)dz.$$
Now I will compute the integrals. This integral $\int_r^Rf(z)dz$ will not be my focus since the argument will be zero. My focus is on
$$\int_R^rf(z)dz$$
I rewrite the integral above to
$$\int_R^rf(z)dz=\int_R^r  \frac{z^{\frac{1}{3}}}{z^2+\pi^2} dz=\int_R^r  \frac{z^{\frac{1}{3}}e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}}{z^2+\pi^2} dz=e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}\int_R^r  \frac{z^{\frac{1}{3}}}{z^2+\pi^2} dz=-e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}\int_r^R  \frac{z^{\frac{1}{3}}}{z^2+\pi^2} dz$$
Now combining
$$(1-e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i})\int_0^\infty \frac{z^{1/3}}{z^2+\pi^2}dz$$
Hence,
$$\oint f(z)dz=(1-e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i})\int_0^\infty \frac{z^{1/3}}{z^2+\pi^2}dz$$
Finding the poles gives me $z^2+\pi^2=0\Leftrightarrow z=\pm \pi i$. By Residue theorem we have the following,
$$2\pi i (\text{Res}\{f(z);z=\pi i\}+\text{Res}\{f(z);z=-\pi i\})=i\pi^{1/3}.$$
And now I get a crazy number and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{z^{1/3}}{z^2+\pi^2}dz=\frac{i\pi^{1/3}}{1-e^{\frac{2}{3}\pi i}}.$$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I know why I did end up with a crazy number. I forgot to work with $\exp(\frac{1}{3}\ln|z|+i \arg(z))$ when computing the residues...